# CollectionView not showing API data names

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to follow a video made by my teacher on how to display certain data in your CollectionView, XamarinForms Application. Yet, while following everything step by step - with the only difference being using another API - the names of my structures aren't showing in the ItemsSource.

I'm certainly doing something wrong, but I just can't seem to figure out what. My goal is to display all the structures names in the CollectionView.

My ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AoFStructures"
             Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing"
             x:Class="AoFStructures.StructureOverview">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Structures"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <CollectionView
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyStructureName, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStructure,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ContentPage.cs

```
    public partial class StructureOverview : ContentPage
    {
        private StructureInfo _structureName;

        public StructureInfo MyStructureName
        {
            get { return _structureName; }
            set { _structureName = value;    OnPropertyChanged("MyStructureName"); }
        }

        private Structure _selectedStructure

        public Structure SelectedStructure
        {
        get {return _selectedStructure;}
        set{_selectedStructure = value; }
        }

        public StructureOverview()
        {
            BindingContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StructureInfo info = await StructureWrapper.GetStructure();
            if (info != null)
            {
                MyStructureName= info;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
```

My API connection

```
ublic class StructureWrapper
    {
            public static async Task<StructureInfo> GetStructure(string UriString = @"https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/structures")
            {
                Uri request = new Uri(UriString);

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "AoFStructures");
                HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync(request);
                if (respons.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                string content = await respons.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                StructureInfo structureInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StructureInfo>(content);

                return structureInfo;
            }
        
    }
```

And my JSON properties:

```
public class Cost
    {

        [JsonProperty("Wood")]
        public int Wood { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Stone")]
        public int? Stone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Gold")]
        public int? Gold { get; set; }
    }

    public class Structure
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expansion")]
        public string Expansion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cost")]
        public Cost Cost { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("build_time")]
        public int BuildTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hit_points")]
        public int HitPoints { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("line_of_sight")]
        public int LineOfSight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("armor")]
        public string Armor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("special")]
        public IList<string> Special { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reload_time")]
        public double? ReloadTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("range")]
        public object Range { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attack")]
        public int? Attack { get; set; }
    }

    public class StructureInfo
    {

        [JsonProperty("structures")]
        public IList<Structure> Structures { get; set; }
    }
```

The API does return the following content:

```
 "structures": [
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Barracks", 
      "expansion": "Age of Kings", 
      "age": "Dark", 
      "cost": {
        "Wood": 175
      }, 
      "build_time": 50, 
      "hit_points": 1200, 
      "line_of_sight": 5, 
      "armor": "0/7", 
      "special": [
        "Garrison: 10 created units"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "Dock", 
      "expansion": "Age of Kings", 
      "age": "Dark", 
      "cost": {
        "Wood": 150
      }, 
      "build_time": 35, 
      "hit_points": 1800, 
      "line_of_sight": 5, 
      "armor": "0/7", 
      "special": [
        "Garrison: 10 created units"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: You are binding `SelectedStructure` in both SelectedItem and ItemsSource or it a typo? that doesn't sound good

Comment: That's a typo I hadn't fixed yet, my bad

Comment: `ItemsSource` must be an `IEnumerable`, and `SelectedStructure` is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsSource` must be an `IEnumerable` (ie, a collection or array of data) and yours is not

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyStructureName, Mode=OneWay}"
```

I suspect you want to do

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyStructureName.Structures}"
```

Comment: This sadly didn't work either, now if I recall correctly and understand this properly whenever you bind a variable it should display a list of options you want to show in your itemsource, in this case I don't get any options but converter, converterparmeters etc.. So I truyl think there's something wrong with the binding structure

Comment: Nevermind, this actually worked! If I added `, mode=OneWay` afterwards then it does display all the names, I came to this conclusion as well with a classmate. Thank you so much!